# How can I prove that the angles of the tetrahedral structure is $109.5^\circ$ with calculus. I could do it with geometry.

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry

How can I prove that the dihedral angles of the regular tetrahedral structure is $109.5^\circ$ with calculus or any other technique. I could do it with geometry by considering a cube.

Comment: Does the dot product count as "calculus"?

Comment: Yes, sure...actually I was looking for new methods.

Comment: Yes, Certainly...thank you for pointing out!

Comment: You only need the cosine law if I am not mistaken, so it is certainly possible.

Comment: What are the "angles of a regular tetrahedral structure"?

Comment: angle subtended by the vertices of a regular tetrahedral structure to the centre

Comment: I changed $109.5^o$ to $109.5^\circ.$ That is standard usage. $\qquad$

Comment: Related: [Is there any mathematical or logical prove for carbon with 4 different groups would be chiral?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119816/is-there-any-mathematical-or-logical-prove-for-carbon-with-4-different-groups-wo/119823#119823)

Answer (score 5):

Four unit vectors pointing outward from the origin have equal angles between them.

By symmetry, their average, and hence their sum, is $0.$

Let a coordinate axis go out from the origin in the direction of one of those four vectors.

The component of that one vector on that axis is $1.$

Therefore sum of the components, on that axis, of the other three, must be $-1.$

Since there are three of them, the component of each on that axis is $-1/3.$

So the cosine of the angle is $-1/3.$

Comment: Or a more algebraic version of this answer: If the center of the tetrahedron is at the origin and the four vertices are at unit vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z},\mathbf{t}$, then $\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{z} + \mathbf{t} = \mathbf{0}$, and taking dot products we get $\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{z} + \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{t} = 0$, so $1 + 3\cos(\theta) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the (theoretical) angle associated with [sp$^{3}$ hybrid orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation). ("Theoretical" because in any molecule where this shows up, there are other forces at work that cause the angle differ by various amounts.) As Ian Mateus said in a comment, you just need the Law of Cosines for a triangle.

Assume the cube has edge length $1$. (The angles will be the same for each value you use for the edge length, so just pick a nice number like $1$.) Then the face diagonals have length $\sqrt{2}$ and the space diagonals have length $\sqrt{3}.$ You can find the space diagonal length by two appropriate applications of the Pythagorean theorem, or by using the distance formula in ${\mathbb R}^3$ to find the distance between $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1).$

By drawing a picture (maybe someone can post a nice diagram), it follows that you want to find the angle $\theta$ formed by the equal-length sides of a triangle whose sides have lengths $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{2}.$ To do this, use the Law of Cosines with $\theta$ as the angle and $\sqrt{2}$ as the side opposite $\theta$:

$$c^2 \; = \; a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos \theta$$

$$\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2 \;\; = \;\; \left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)^2 \; + \;  \left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)^2 \; - \; 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)\cos \theta$$

$$ 2 \; = \; \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4} - \frac{3}{2}\cos \theta $$

$$ \frac{1}{2} \; = \; - \frac{3}{2} \cos \theta $$

$$ - \frac{1}{3} = \cos \theta$$

$$ \theta = \arccos \left( -\frac{1}{3} \right) $$

Now use a calculator.

*(ADDED 4 YEARS 5 MONTHS LATER)* A few months ago (from the date of this edit) I came across several papers in **Journal of Chemical Education** that give various ways of deriving the tetrahedral bond angle. I put the papers aside at the time, intending to include them here at some later time, and now is that later time.

**[1]** Gordon Louis Gombert, [*The valence angle of the carbon atom*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed018p336), **Journal of Chemical Education** 18 #7 (July 1941), 336-337.

**[2]** Walter Harrington Dore, [*Calculation of the valence angle*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed019p29), **Journal of Chemical Education** 19 #1 (January 1942), 29-30.

**[3]** Philip Francis Weatherill, [*The valence angle of the carbon atom*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed019p35), **Journal of Chemical Education** 19 #1 (January 1942), 35.

**[4]** Garrett William Thiessen, [*The carbon valence angle*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed019p198), Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 19 #4 (April 1942), 198.

**[5]** Wesley Emil Brittin, [*Valence angle of the tetrahedral carbon atom*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed022p145), **Journal of Chemical Education** 22 #3 (March 1945), 145.

**[6]** Thomas McCullough, [*Simple calculation of the tetrahedral bond angle*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed039p476), **Journal of Chemical Education** 39 #9 (September 1962), 476.

**[7]** Günther Snatzke, [[Letter to the Editor](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed040p94.1)], Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 40 #2 (February 1963), 94. [Note: There is a typo in the first displayed equation, and it should be $r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4 = 0.]$

**[8]** Bruce Lindsey Cockburn, [[Letter to the Editor](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed040p94.2)], Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 40 #2 (February 1963), 94.

**[9]** Christopher James Kawa, [*Finding the bond angle in a tetrahedral-shaped molecule*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed065p884), **Journal of Chemical Education** 65 #10 (October 1988), 884-885.

**[10]** George Henry Duffey, [*Employing vector algebra to obtain the tetrahedral bond angle*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed067p35), **Journal of Chemical Education** 67 #1 (January 1990), 35-36.

**[11]** Dylan Gow and Amites Sarkar, [Solution to Problem 22.5], **Mathematical Spectrum** 23 #1 (September 1990), 27-28.

**[12]** Resat Mustafa Apak and Izzet Tor, [Finding the bond angle](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed068p970.2), Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 68 #11 (November 1991), 970.

**[13]** Brian Terence Sutcliffe and Stephen J. Smith, [Computing the tetrahedral angle](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed069p171.1), Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 69 #2 (February 1992), 171.

**[14]** George Henry Duffey, [Computing the tetrahedral angle](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed069p171.2), Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 69 #2 (February 1992), 171.

**[15]** Paul Glaister, [*Rotational symmetry of a methane molecule and the bond angle*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed070p351), **Journal of Chemical Education** 70 #5 (May 1993), 351.

**[16]** Paul Glaister, [*Calculating the tetrahedral bond angle using spherical polars and the dot product*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed070p546), **Journal of Chemical Education** 70 #7 (July 1993), 546-547.

**[17]** Alfred Alexander Woolf, [*Tetrahedral geometry made simple*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed072p19), **Journal of Chemical Education** 72 #1 (January 1995), 19-20.

**[18]** Paul Glaister, [*Two comments on bond angles*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed074p1086), **Journal of Chemical Education** 74 #9 (September 1997), 1086.

**[19]** Ricardo de Carvalho Ferreira, [Tetrahedral bond angle](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ed075p1087.3), Letters section, **Journal of Chemical Education** 75 #9 (September 1998), 1087.

**[20]** Sara Noemí Mendiara and Luis José Perissinotti, [*Tetrahedral geometry and the dipole moment of molecules*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed079p64), **Journal of Chemical Education** 79 #1 (January 2002), 64-66.

**[21]** Marten J. ten Hoor, [*An evergreen: the tetrahedral bond angle*](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed079p956), **Journal of Chemical Education** 79 #8 (August 2002), 956-957.

Comment: If you are stuck in an island, you can compute it using [$$\cos^{-1}(-1/3)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2k\choose k}\frac{(-1/3)^{2k+1}}{4^{k}(2k+1)}$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series)

Answer (score 1):

With dot products: Taking the axis-oriented cube of side length $2$ centered at the origin, you're looking for the angle $\theta$ between (say) the vectors $\mathbf{u} = (1, -1, 1)$ and $\mathbf{v} = (-1, 1, 1)$:
$$
\cos\theta = \frac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{u}\|\, \|\mathbf{v}\|}
  = -\frac{1}{3}.
$$
In response to Dave Renfro's request for a diagram (his triangles are bounded by a pair of vectors and a dashed line), here's a crossed-eyes stereogram:

[image: Tetrahedral stereogram]

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazing geometric interpretation for figuring out the angle in that link ->

http://maze5.net/?page_id=367

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Please describe the content of the link rather than just posting the link.