# Proof of the VSEPR shapes.

Tags: geometry, 3d, chemistry

> The VSEPR(Valence Shell Electron Pair Repulsion) predicts that the atoms arrange themselves in such a way that the electron pair repulsion is minimized. Thus the atoms arrange themselves in space in such a manner so as to be as far apart as possible.
>
> What I was wondering was that how do one prove that the shapes are correctly predicted?
>
> For example if looking at the molecule CH4, how do i prove that for maximum distance between the H atoms, they have to arrange themselves around the C atom in a tetrahedral shape.

Restatement:

**If I have a ball fixed in space and have four other balls that I have to arrange around it, provided that the 4 balls are at the same finite distance from the fixed ball, how do i prove that the four balls must form a tetrahedral for having the maximum distance between them?**

This question was originally posted on [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/105684/proof-of-the-vsepr-shapes?noredirect=1#comment198443_105684), where a user told me post this question here.

Comment: I believe you were told wrong.  If anyone here is able to answer your chemistry question, it will be pure luck.

Comment: Given four points (not coplanar) they will form a tetrahedron (not necessarily regular). But since the four H- atoms have the same attributes, then you will necessarily have a regular tetrahedron. In some sense the answer is obvious, but if you want to show this from the level of the many-body Schrodinger equation then that is a whole other story.

Comment: @JackyChong But why a tetrahedron and not any other shape like a square? Does the answer involve some very complex math?

Comment: Similar questions with some great answers were asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710388/why-is-arccos-frac-13-the-optimal-angle-between-bonds-in-a-methane-rm-c?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663259/how-can-i-prove-that-the-angles-of-the-tetrahedral-structure-is-109-5-circ-wi), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56847/angle-between-lines-joining-tetrahedron-center-to-vertices?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59161/calculations-of-angles-between-bonds-in-ch%E2%82%84-methane-molecule?rq=1)

Comment: @Dibbs These do not answer my question as all of these refer to finding the angles of a tetrahedral.